# urllib.request.urlopen() socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I created very simple program that access url and download html.
There are 2,000 urls. (The site owner accept access.)
I encountered the following error.

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The error occured not at the same timing. 
I couldn't understand in which the error caused `python3`, `urllib`, `linux` or not.
Do you have any ideas to inspect the error?

## error log

```
type:<class 'urllib.error.URLError'>
args:(gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

## source

```
import codecs
from urllib import request
import traceback

class Accessor():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def convert(self):

        beforeDataFile = codecs.open("url.csv","r", "cp932")
        cnt=1
        for line in beforeDataFile:
            try:
                cnt=cnt+1
                request_url = line
                print(request_url)
                response = request.urlopen(request_url)
                print(cnt,request_url,response)
            except Exception as e:
                print("=== ERROR ===")
                print("type:" + str(type(e)))
                print('args:' + str(e.args))
                print("message:" + e.message)
                print(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == "__main__":

     a = Accessor()
     a.convert()
```

## url.py

```
   1 https://www.google.co.jp/
   2 https://www.google.co.jp/
   3 https://www.google.co.jp/
   4 https://www.google.co.jp/
   5 https://www.google.co.jp/
~~~
1995 https://www.google.co.jp/
1996 https://www.google.co.jp/
1997 https://www.google.co.jp/
1998 https://www.google.co.jp/
1999 https://www.google.co.jp/
2000 https://www.google.co.jp/
```

## environment

CentOS 7.1.1503
Python3.5.1

Comment: You should output the failing URL.

Comment: Not sure how it worked well with newlines on the urls using urllib2.  As far as I can see it would fail for the same reason on both.

Comment: DNS lookups are subject to network and cache availability. This isn't a Python 3 vs 2 problem, this is a DNS lookup problem. What hostname failed?

Comment: Thank you. I tried using dummy url `https://www.google.co.jp/`, the error happend not only Python3.5.1 but also Python2.7.1 
I changed the question title.